# Android Capture Image and pass along activity result

Tags: android, android-camera

Right now I have this code.

CameraActivity.class

```
private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //make a new picture file
            File pictureFile = null;
            try {
                pictureFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("cameraresult", imagePath);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            //refresh camera to continue preview
            //mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    };
    return picture;
}

OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });

    }
};

//make picture and save to a folder

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "TIMEKEEPER_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    imagePath =  image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

And MainActivity.class

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // 카메라 결과
    else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            String cameraresult = data.getStringExtra("cameraresult");
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(cameraresult));
            //final Uri imageUri = photoURI;
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            **selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);**
            byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
            String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            String image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgString;
            selectedImage.recycle();
```

What I am trying to make is havine the cameraactivity send the file path of the taken picture and the mainactivity turns the path into uri and encodeds to base64.
But in the MainActivity.class the selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);**
 part has an error. I cant figure out what causes this. Can someone help me?

Comment: did app crashes?

Comment: post the error log